# does C++ have a self initializing pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I am a bit embarrassed of asking such a simple question:

Is there any pointer class in cpp that initializes itself with `nullptr` but is 100% compatible to a basic c-stylish pointer?

to write:

```
extern "C" void someFunction(const Struct* i_s);

std::ptr<Struct> p;
// ...
p = new Struct;
// ...
someFunction(p);
```

Is there such a thing?
Or maybe in boost or Qt?

Edit: to make it clear: iam not searching for a smart pointer that takes ownership of the pointer and does ref counting.

Comment: I can't see that being very useful. It's no easier or harder to enforce the use of this than to enforce initialisation of raw pointers. And saying `= nullptr` gives better documentation than using a funny type.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Just out of interest, what's your opinion on http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3840.pdf (`std::observer_ptr`)?

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Probably harmless, but not massively useful. It has the slight advantage of documenting that you're (supposedly) using the pointer for observation and not abusing it for some other purpose, and would let you have a strict "no raw pointers" policy if you though such a thing were desirable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following syntax

`std::unique_ptr<Struct> up{};`

(or `std::shared_ptr`). This way, the pointer is value-initialized, i.e. `nullptr` is being assigned to it.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr for details about the default constructor.

---

If you looking for a "smart" pointer that just initialized by default with `nullptr`, then you can write a wrapper. A *very* basic version below:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct safe_ptr
{
    T* _ptr;
    explicit safe_ptr(T* ptr = nullptr):_ptr{ptr}{}
    operator T*() const {return _ptr;}
    safe_ptr& operator=(T* rhs)
    {
        _ptr = rhs;
        return *this;
    }
};

void test(int* p){}

int main()
{
    safe_ptr<int> s;
    if(s==nullptr)
        std::cout << "Yes, we are safe!" << std::endl;
    // test that it "decays"
    test(s);

    s = new int[10]; // can assign 
    delete[] s; // can delete
}
```

Comment: the pointer should not take ownership of the given Pointer. It should just ensure that it is zero-initialized. 100% compatible also means in terms of memory management.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch it doesn't take ownership of `nullptr`, there is no such thing. It is value-initialized, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr

Comment: @vlad_tepesch Are you looking for a "smart" pointer that just initialized by default with `nullptr`? If yes, you can write a wrapper.

Comment: sure it is always possible to write something by my own but its always better to do not have to write it by my own.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch: And that's certainly the correct attitude.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch then I guess the answer to your question is "No, C++ doesn't have such a type (at least not in common libraries I am aware of" :)

Comment: By the way, you have used the wrong `delete` there. It should be `delete[] s`.

Comment: that brings me to an interesting question: how can this be handled by smart pointers that cannot distinguish if they have to use `delete`or `delete[]` to free their pointers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing in C++ since all of the special pointer classes implement some form of ownership other than "maintained by someone else". You could *technically* use `shared_ptr` with an empty deleter but that adds reference counting you don't actually need.

The correct C++ solution is to just always add `= 0;` or `= nullptr;` to your raw pointer declarations that aren't initialized at declaration.

All that said, this question is tagged just as C++ so the idiomatic answer is to not use raw pointers in your code (except for non-owning cases obviously).

Answer (score 1):

> 100% compatible to a basic c-stylish pointer

`std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` do not have automatic conversions to a raw pointer, and that's a good thing as it would inevitably lead to horrible bugs. They take ownership, and in your comments you explicitly say:

> the pointer should not take ownership of the given Pointer.

If you *insist*, you can define a "smart" pointer class yourself:

```
template <class T>
class RawPointer final
{
private:
    T* raw_ptr;
public:
    RawPointer(T* raw_tr) : raw_ptr(raw_ptr) {}
    RawPointer() : raw_ptr(nullptr) {}
    operator T*() const { return raw_ptr; }
};

struct Struct
{
};

void someFunction(const Struct* i_s);

int main()
{
    RawPointer<Struct> p;
    someFunction(p);
}
```

Is this a good idea? Probably not. You should just **get into the habit of initializing** your raw pointers:

```
Struct* p = nullptr;
```

On the other hand, people are thinking about a very similar addition to the standard library in the future. You may find [A Proposal for the World’s Dumbest Smart Pointer](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3840.pdf) an interesting read.

Answer (score 1):

If this is really the behavior that you want, it would be trivial to implement it yourself in a template. Here's one such implementation:

```
template<class T>
class ptr_t{
    T* ptr;
public:
    ptr_t() : ptr(nullptr){ }       
    ptr_t(const ptr_t& other) : ptr(other.ptr){ }
    ptr_t(T* other) : ptr(other){ }
    T& operator*(){
        return *ptr;
    }
    T* operator->(){
        return ptr;
    }
    template<class U>
    operator U(){
        return (U)ptr;
    }
}
```

However, the amount of convenience you will gain from such a device will be rather limited. You're probably much better off taking another approach.

Comment: You should use initialization, not assignment. OTOH, you took the trouble and defined some extra operations I was too lazy to show in my example, e.g. `operator->`.

Comment: I moved the assignments into initializer lists just for you. However, since pointers are basic integer primitives the generated code will likely be identical.

Comment: Yes, the generated code will likely be identical, but IMHO one should always initialize (if possible) for consistency reasons.